# What is the best and simplest http user agent in .NET?

Tags: .net, http, user-agent

What is the best and simplest http user agent in .NET?

I simply want to put in the url have it return the page as a string.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "user agent"? Do you just want a library that handles URL requests? Or do you want some lightweight application that you can send HTTP requests and view them in a raw-form?

Comment: Defintion of 'user agent': en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@ion todriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90843/ion-todirel), a suggestion based on [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace myHttpWebRequest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string page = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the line `string page = reader.ReadToEnd ();` - return the whole page as a string.

This is not more complicated than the earlier
[`System.Net.WebClinet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)
with an example in the reference document.

Comment: Simple, yet doomed. WebClient it's very poorly written, it inherits from Component, it needs to be disposed, and it's impractical in real-world scenarios where server response are sometimes beyond 1 second (WebClient does not set a timeout interval and the default one is quite small). Do yourself a favor an use WebRequest.